# Is endpoint pH concentration dependent? Choosing an acid/base indicator

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry, ph, titration

We use titrations to determine analyte concentrations with a standardized titrant and an acid/base indicator, BUT how do we choose the indicator? It is my understanding that indicators are supposed to be matched to the endpoint pH of your titration, but unless you already know the concentration of the analyte in solution, how do we determine the endpoint pH to match the indicator to? And if we already know the concentration of our analyte, doesn't that defeat the purpose of the titration in the first place?

I must be missing something...

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8048/shouldnt-the-ph-at-the-equivalence-point-always-be-7 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8653/the-significance-of-the-dissociation-constant-of-an-indicator

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator